# VS 2013 debugging very slow IIS start

Tags: c#, debugging, iis, visual-studio-2013, performance

When I am working in a project that several of my colleagues work in too I have significantly longer starting time of IIS than the others.

Almost every page in the application takes ages (the first time) but after that it goes smooth. The difference in loading time is like 1-2 seconds for my colleagues and 5-12 seconds for me. My computer is BY FAR the most powerful in terms of internal memory, hard disk speed, CPU speed and more. Almost twice as fast as others, but still I get this problem.

I don't have any other problems with my machine.
We all use: VS 2013, Chrome 35.019, C#
I use: IIS version 8.5, Windows 8.1
Colleagues use: IIS version ?, Windows 7 and Windows 8

Comment: Today it's even worse. The pages that takes 1-2 seconds to load for my colleagues takes me over 2 minutes! Frustrating!

Comment: I found the problem... When I run Spotify on my computer it is slow. Ok, I run Spotify through a bluetooth gateway and to my bluetooth headset, but I was still very surprised to see it.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spotify can affect VS and IIS performance on certain hardware. If you have this problem and you are using Spotify, try to turn it off and see if it works better.